# Repeated questions problem

Tags: support

What should happen to questions that are repeated again but have a post note that says 'Sorry if this is already discussed. Couldn't find the post.'? (Due to negligence of asker repeatedly). Should they be answered with links or flagged to get moderator attention for merging?

Sorry if this is already discussed. Couldn't find the post. :)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you can identify an earlier question that is basically the same, vote to close the new question as a duplicate, giving the link to the earlier question.

If you don't have enough rep to vote to close, you can either skip it and let others handle it, or flag for moderator attention.  If it's really a blatant duplicate, others will catch it soon enough.  It's probably not worth bothering mods about something that basic that plenty of ordinary users can take care of for them.

Another option is to write a comment saying that you think this is a duplicate, and providing the link.  That makes it really easy for those with higher rep to check out the supposed duplicate and vote to close if they feel it really is a dupe.

Comment: Just a note on this, if you have the 15 rep to be able to flag for moderator attention you can flag to close as a duplicate so it just goes onto the normal close queue (without an actual close vote) and it still posts the automatic "possible duplicate" comment.